# When does combat advantage end with push effects and deadly draw?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, forced-movement

I built a Centered Breath monk with Deadly Draw and I as well have the "Gauntlets of the Ram" which allow me to "Add 1 to the distance of any push effect you create."

Let's assume an enemy is directly in front of me and I hit it. When it comes to the Flurry power resolution, I push it one field to the right, so it still is adjacent to me and I get CA. Because I pushed it, I can push it another square due to the gauntlets. In the end I pushed it two squares and the enemy is not adjacent any more.

Because it now isn't adjacent any more, do I still get the CA bonus from sliding it adjacent? I pushed it two squares, but because I slid the enemy adjacent with the first square, I should get CA against the enemy. Even if I pushed it one further. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes and no**

Yes, you gain combat advantage until the end of your next turn with Deadly Draw, no matter where he ends up.

Everything else, you got completely wrong:

- Gauntlets of the Ram adds to pushes, but Centered Breath slides. Push and slide is different.
- You can not push "one field to the right", it would be a slide. Luckily it can be done with Centered Breath.
- You did *not* push, so you do not get to push 1 square further. The direction of the slide does not make it a push. There are some powers and items that can turn a push into a slide, but it is always *one or the other*.
- Even if Gauntlets of the Ram gave a bonus to slides, the limitations of Flurry of Blows would still apply. If you slide the *target* of the triggering attack, you can only slide it to an adjacent square. So even with a Rushing Cleats (it gives a bonus to *slides*), you still have to slide it to an adjacent square.

In conclusion:

- Gauntlets of the Ram is completely useless for the Centered Breath Flurry of Blows, but you can use it with actual push powers.
- The position *after* sliding to adjacent is irrelevant for Deadly Draw. If the enemy was adjacent to you for just a moment, you get Combat Advantage.

Comment: Thank you, the reason why I thought sliding the enemy one square to the right would count as pushing is because the manual says that the target must be moved further away. Strictly speaking, the target is then further away when drawn a line between the centers of the squares.
But I could push a creature two squares with my Flurry and gauntlets, if that creature wasn't targeted by the triggering attack. Right?

Comment: @telandor: For all rules purposes, measure distances in 4E by counting squares, not by measuring distance to centre of squares. By that, all adjacent squares are the same distance away, and you cannot *push* (or pull) a target from one adjacent square to another.

Comment: @telandor in other words, even if you were to measure the distance to the centre of the squares, both squares would be *one square away*, which is *the same distance*, which is not *further away*

Comment: When I move an enemy with the Flurry which wasn't targeted by the triggering attack, I can slide that enemy any direction. This means I can slide it away from me. This would be a push effect then and the gauntlets are usable. Is this correct?

Comment: @telandor: no, see my update.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a problem, currently, because you're using two different keywords - Push and Slide. A *Push* allows you to move a target away from you, while a *Slide* allows you to move it in any direction. The Gauntlets of the Ram item won't affect your Flurry of Blows power.

If you were using an item that increased Slide distance instead, such as the Rushing Cleats, I don't think you'd be able to slide the enemy away from you in this fashion. When you increase the size of the effect, it's applied all at once, so using Centered Flurry of Blows slides the enemy 2 squares to a square adjacent to you.

However, if you have a feat that gives you an extra Slide / Push, such as Mark of Storm, this is possible to do. You'll get Deadly Draw's CA triggered off of the Centered Flurry of Blows slide, and then the additional Slide / Push will move them away. Deadly Draw's CA is a Conditional Duration, that lasts until the End of your Next Turn and won't be cancelled because they moved away, by Forced Movement or normal movement.